# Why for ideal gases , dU=nCvdT is always valid ?? I just know the formula but i didn't know the source from where this formula came or derived

Tags: thermodynamics

So my question is:**why ideal gas have same formula for every situation and how the formula is derive???**

Comment: If a question is asked on Chemistry SE site, then, in contrary to sites like Quora, it is expected from the author to elaborate the topic of the question by doing at least basic own topic review, writing what he/she has found and understood, and what is the stumble stone. The quick questions without explicitly expressed particular effort are not very welcome, and may be closed.

Comment: Question titles should be like book titles. They distinguish the book from
other books, give a hint about content, but do not tell the full story. The content should then elaborate the topic to full depth the author is able to do.

Answer (score 1):

For pure substances and mixtures of constant composition, you will learn later that the more general equation for dU is $$dU=nC_vdT-\left[P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\right]dV$$For an ideal gas, the second term is exactly zero.